# Replacing the Node text with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my XML file, which is used to stored the data -

```
<Locations>
   <location>
      <place>Newyork</place>
      <dt>01-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Berlin</place>
      <dt>02-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Tokyo</place>
      <dt>04-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
</Location>
```

What I want to achieve is -

I want to replace the `<dt>` tags date value, if the visit is re-scheduled. For example- 
If the visit date for Berlin is changed, stored in `<dt>` tags, then how to edit/replace the same
in the XML file using XSLT..? Thanks in advance - John

Comment: Good question, +1. Overriding the identity rule and passing the update(s) as an external parameter to the transformation -- is the both short and most powerful solution to this problem.

Comment: @Dimitre- Right said and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation shows how to use a global parameter (modelled here with an inline element) to specify (possibly multiple) updates**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:updates>
  <update place="Berlin" dt="11-Dec-2011"/>
 </my:updates>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "location
     [place = document('')/*/my:updates/update/@place]
       /dt/text()
  ">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "document('')/*/my:updates/update
                      [@place = current()/../../place]
                        /@dt
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to make it well-formed):

```
<Locations>
   <location>
      <place>Newyork</place>
      <dt>01-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Berlin</place>
      <dt>02-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Tokyo</place>
      <dt>04-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
</Locations>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Locations>
   <location>
      <place>Newyork</place>
      <dt>01-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Berlin</place>
      <dt>11-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Tokyo</place>
      <dt>04-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
</Locations>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule copies every node "as-is**".
2. **There is just one overriding template** -- matching the text-node child of any `dt` whose `place` sibling's string value has a corresponding `my:updates/update` element. In this template we output the value of the `dt` attribute of this corresponding `my:updates/update` element.

**Do note**: In a realworld transformation the inline `my:updates` element will be better replaced by an external, global parameter. Read your XSLT processor's documentation how to pass an external parameter to the transformation -- this is implementation-dependent.

**UPDATE**: As the OP has found it difficult to convert this solution to one using global, externally passed `xsl:param`, here is this converted solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUpdates">
  <update place="Berlin" dt="11-Dec-2011"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpdates" select=
     "ext:node-set($pUpdates)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dt/text()">
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="../../place=$vUpdates/@place">
       <xsl:value-of select=
           "$vUpdates[@place = current()/../../place]/@dt"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct and wanted result is produced**:

```
<Locations>
   <location>
      <place>Newyork</place>
      <dt>01-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Berlin</place>
      <dt>11-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
   <location>
      <place>Tokyo</place>
      <dt>04-Dec-2011</dt>
   </location>
</Locations>
```

**Do note**: In this solution the `xsl:param` still has its value hardcoded and this is the only reason we are using the `ext:node-set()` extension function. If the parameter is really passed from outside, then this convertion from RTF to a regular tree isn't necessary and the parameter should be referenced directly.

**Also, in XSLT 1.0 we have to match more inexactly** and to use comparisons (the `xsl:choose`) inside the body of the template. This is so because in XSLT 1.0 it isn't allowed to reference variables/parameters inside the match-pattern.

**In XSLT 2.0 this limitation has been eliminated**, so we can just have a much simpler transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUpdates">
  <update place="Berlin" dt="11-Dec-2011"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "location[place=$pUpdates/*/@place]/dt/text()">
       <xsl:value-of select=
           "$pUpdates/*[@place = current()/../../place]/@dt"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. for a very clear and concise explanation. Hats off to you :)

Comment: So while passing parameters, I will have to use the following tag - /<xsl:param name="paraPlace" select=""/>` and `<xsl:param name="paraDate" select=""/>` and will have use these parameters in the `<my:update...>` tag. Right..?

Comment: I am getting following error - --------------------Configuration: '<Default>--------------------
ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Premature end of file.'
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:' when trying to update the same xml file. But when the transformed XML file is different then NO ERRORs !!

Comment: @John: I have updated the answer with the corresponding transformation to be used with a global `<xsl:param>`. I also provide a simpler and shorter XSLT 2.0 solution, in case you can use XSLT 2.0. Hope this answers your new questions.

Answer (score 2):

The identity template will copy the document:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can make other templates only for the parts you want to change.

Example (untested):

```
<xsl:template match="//location/dt[preceding-sibling::place='Berlin']">
    <dt>Your date</dt>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The real question is, how are you gonna check if a visit is re-scheduled? The way I see it, you've got three options:

- Store the re-scheduled dates with places in a secondary XML and use the XPath `document` function to read from it;
- generate an XSLT stylesheet programmatically with the corrections already in place or
- use an XSLT extension function or extension element (function would probably suffice) to perform the checks in some other language. For example Java.

EDIT - or follow Krab's excellent suggestion: use XSLT parameters in a way that lets you pass in the data to an otherwise static stylesheet.

Comment: Hey, what about stylesheet parameters - just pass it place and new date.

Comment: @Krab Of course... I really should remember you can pass in params. Who knows what crazy stylesheet generating I've done that could've been avoided. Gonna edit that in.