# Update nodes via merge without changing node order?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

#### Background

I'd like to update an XML file by merging new content into an existing file. Everything in the existing file (A) should be left unchanged except for the content to be merged (file B), in this case, 'description' nodes.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006946/replacing-the-node-text-with-xslt). However, a limitation I've encountered with the answer suggested is that node order is not necessarily preserved. I would like original node order to be preserved if possible. My current XSL only does the following:

1. matches the description nodes to be merged, then copies them over - before other nodes.
2. then copies everything else (everything that's not a description).

My XSL and XML are below. Do note that I'm limited to XSLT 1.0

#### XSL

```
<xsl:variable name="desc" select="document('doc.out.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[name=$desc//node/@name]">

    <xsl:variable name="name" select="current()/name" />    

    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$desc//node[@name=$name]/description" />   

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::description)]" />

    </xsl:copy>                             

</xsl:template>
```

#### XML A (to be updated)

```
    <renderer>
        <name>key</name>
        <description>
            The key element is an Object Element used to create and
            identify rows.
        </description>
        <foo>blah</foo>
        <fields>
            <field>
                <name>elements</name>
                <description>
                    A container for all 'element' nodes.
                </description>
                <bar>blah</bar>
                <factory>
                    <localRenderer>
                        <name>element</name>
                        <description>
                            A primitive object and arrays thereof.
                        </description>
                        <baz>blah</baz>
                        <fields>
                            <field>
                                <name>name</name>
                                <description>
                                    Alias by which the element may be referenced.
                                </description>
                                <bar>blah</bar>
                            </field>
                            <field>
                                <name>type</name>
                                <description>
                                    Type of the data.
                                </description>
                                <bar>blah</bar>
                            </field>
                        </fields>
                    </localRenderer>
                </factory>
            </field>
        </fields>
    </renderer>
```

#### XML B (contains content to be merged into A)

```
<root>
    <node name="key">
        <description>The key element is an Object Element used to create and
            identify rows.Note that object declaration via XML must occur within
            a definitions element. See for more information.</description>
        <subnodes>
            <node name="elements">
                <description>
                Hi. This is a  test.
                </description>
                <subnodes>
                    <node name="element">
                        <description>A primitive object and arrays thereof. TEST</description>
                        <subnodes>
                            <node name="name">
                                <description>Alias by which the element may be referenced.
                                </description>
                            </node>
                            <node name="type">
                                <description>Type of the data; a primitive object of array
                                    thereof. </description>
                            </node>
                        </subnodes>
                    </node>
                </subnodes>
            </node>
        </subnodes>
    </node>
</root>
```

#### Current Output

Note that description is now the first node.

```
    <renderer>
        <description>The key element is an Object Element used to create and
            identify rows.Note that object declaration via XML must occur within
            a definitions element. See for more information.
        </description>
        <name>key</name>
        <foo>blah</foo>
        <fields>
            <field>
                <description>
                    Hi. This is a test.
                </description>
                <name>elements</name>
                <bar>blah</bar>
                <factory>
                    <localRenderer>
                        <description>A primitive object and arrays thereof. TEST
                        </description>
                        <name>element</name>
                        <baz>blah</baz>
                        <fields>
                            <field>
                                <description>Alias by which the element may be referenced.
                                </description>
                                <name>name</name>
                                <bar>blah</bar>
                            </field>
                            <field>
                                <description>Type of the data; a primitive object of array
                                    thereof.
                                </description>
                                <name>type</name>
                                <bar>blah</bar>
                            </field>
                        </fields>
                    </localRenderer>
                </factory>
            </field>
        </fields>
    </renderer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change the `description` nodes in document A, then to preserve the order, you should have a template in your XSLT that matches the `description` node, rather than its parent:

```
 <xsl:template match="description">
```

You would then get the `name` by looking at the preceding-sibling

```
 <xsl:variable name="name" select="preceding-sibling::name[1]" />
```

Then to check whether the node exists in document B, you can use another variable

```
 <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="$desc//node[@name = $name]" />
```

Then it is a simple case of using an `xsl:choose` to determine whether to copy the description from A or B

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$lookup">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup/description" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="desc" select="document('doc.out.xml')" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="preceding-sibling::name[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="$desc//node[@name = $name]" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$lookup">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup/description" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that the reason for using an `xsl:choose` here, rather than putting in the condition in the template match, is because in XSLT 1.0 (according to the [W3C XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Defining-Template-Rules)) *It is an error for the value of the match attribute to contain a VariableReference*.

This means the template match `<xsl:template match="//*[name=$desc//node/@name]">` in your XSLT is strictly speaking an error (although some XSLT 1.0 processors may not follow the spec and allow it, as in your case)

Comment: This template does the trick. +1 for informing me about the 1.0 error.